# Yii2 Update where the condition is an Array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, yii2

This is the update code

```
 $clients = OpClient::find(['id'])->where(['status'=>'Active'])->all();

    foreach($clients as $client)
    {
        $array[] = $client['unit_id'];
        $unit = OpUnit::find()->where(['id'=>$array]);

         file_put_contents('test.txt',print_r($client['unit_id'],true));

         $connection = Yii::$app->db;
        $connection->createCommand()->update('op_unit', ['selected' => 'Yes'], 'id='.$array.'')->execute();
    }
```

How should I type in the update query where the id is an array? It keep showing error `Array to string conversion`. Any advice will be apprecieated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

should be this way  ..

```
$connection->createCommand()->update('user', 
             ['selected' => 'Yes'],['id' => $array])->execute();
```

try the real sql code  using

```
$myRawSql=   $connection->createCommand()->update('user', 
             ['selected' => 'Yes'],['id' => $array])>getRawSql();

var_dump($myRawSql);
```

Comment: i tried this too. It shows no error but the database did not update :/

Comment: Check generated sql query by `var_dump($connection->createCommand()->update('user', 
             ['selected' => 'Yes'],['id' => $array])->createCommand()->rawSql);die;`

Comment: try check the real rawSql created .. answer  updated  with suggestion

Comment: Okayy. Let me try first

Comment: If you have multiple conditions to check, use following code
$condition = ['and',
                    ['=', 'colmn1', $colmn1Val],
                    ['in', 'colmn2', $arrayValues],
                ];
                
                Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('yourTableName',['columnToUpdate'=>'valueToUpdate'],$condition)->execute();

Answer (score 2):

For searching you can use the `IN` condition. i.e

```
->andWhere(['in', 'id', [1, 2, 3]])
```

> // Query will be: WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
>
> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html
>
> in: operand 1 should be a column or DB expression. Operand 2 can be
>   either an array or a Query object. It will generate an IN condition.
>   If Operand 2 is an array, it will represent the range of the values
>   that the column or DB expression should be; If Operand 2 is a Query
>   object, a sub-query will be generated and used as the range of the
>   column or DB expression. For example, ['in', 'id', [1, 2, 3]] will
>   generate id IN (1, 2, 3). The method will properly quote the column
>   name and escape values in the range. The in operator also supports
>   composite columns. In this case, operand 1 should be an array of the
>   columns, while operand 2 should be an array of arrays or a Query
>   object representing the range of the columns.

So basically you need to pass your array to IN for search.

For update you can use same Where syntax in updateAll command i.e

> // UPDATE `customer` SET `status` = 1 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
>   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#updating-multiple-rows

```
Customer::updateAll(['status' => Customer::STATUS_ACTIVE], ['in', 'id', [1, 2, 3]]);
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: U dont have to use `in`. Using `['id' => $array]` (where `$array` is really array) will generate `in` condition, cause query builder checks, if value is array.

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

You can use `updateAll` query :

```
$update = OpUnit::updateAll(['selected' => 'Yes'],['id' => $array]);
```

It returns number of rows updated.

Refer : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#updateAll()-detail

Comment: i stil cant update when my id is in array`(['1','2'])` . I can update when I put a value to id (example 1). Why??